# How to install and launch Python node inside a virtualenv?

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a Python ROS node, and all the documentation seems to assume I've installed all my package dependencies into the global site-packages. Best practices in the Python world is to use a virtualenv. However, I can't find anything in the tutorials that mentions this. When launching my node, is it enough to source my virtualenv, or is there some special configuration I need to do first?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228490/how-to-install-and-launch-python-node-inside-a-virtualenv?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the python code was written by you and is part of one of your own ROS package then sourcing the ros workspace's devel/setup.bash will make all the python libraries available for import just like virtualenv does. These links should give enough info to set up a ros package to do so.

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-0008.rst

AFAIK there isn't any special configuration needed to use a virtualenv when developing Python nodes. I sourced devel/setup.bash in my ros workspace first, then sourced bin/activate in a virtualenv and found I was able to import modules from both the ros packages and the libraries installed in just the virtualenv.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2016-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-03-09**:
Thanks. I've verified this also.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't matter if you have your own ROS package or whatever, virtualenv is a tool to isolate python environments.
THe first time I was lost, but I found a [guide to learn more about virtualenvs](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/10-whats-is-a-virtualenv-and-how-to-install-it.html).

Hope it helps!!

---

Originally posted by [newbiep](https://answers.ros.org/users/28701/newbiep/) with karma: 21 on 2016-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2